# Selenium: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I just had this code working last night but now it won't work and I am stumped. I am using ChromeDriverManager to ensure the right driver is being downloaded, but I still get the error. I have also tried removing the driver cache, but this doesn't help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get("google.com")
```

From this code I get the error

`selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83`

Edit: I am using Chrome Version 83.0.4103.97 and the ChromeDriver version being downloaded is 83.0.4103.39

Comment: i have aced this problem. i think its bcoz `chrome` updates automatically. just search on google `'chromedriver for chrome 83'` - if that is `chromedriver 83` (which you've mentioned) - just check if you have placed this new version of `chromedriver` in the `path` which you're using in the script

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat I tried that previously but it didn't work. I ended up just downgrading Chrome to version 81 and installing the chromedriver for that version. It ended up working

Comment: I think I am facing the same issue @Aidan though it is giving me a different error. I'm getting `DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist`. My chromedriver and chrome versions are exactly same as what you have mentioned in your question....

Comment: @tanmay_garg Try downgrading chrome to version 81 and get the chromedriver for chrome 81. That's what I did and it works fine now. You can search online how to downgrade your Chrome. Good luck